# Unwanted white space on the right side of html / php page

Tags: php, html, css

I am using an html template for my site.

URL - http://www.tekestate.com/site/easydelivery/index.php

Now I don't know what is wrong with my css because if you see it leaves a unwanted white space on the right which can be scrolled for the mobile version as well as the desktop version.

My CSS (very large to put it here) - http://www.tekestate.com/site/easydelivery/stylesheet/style.css

I looked for the solution but nothing worked as I am not able to figure out where in the problem lies.

[image: Normal Mode]

[image: responsive mode png]

Comment: Please, fix the images link.

Comment: Please post the relevant portions of the CSS here along with the section of HTML/PHP.

Comment: @hotzst : Relevant portion of the CSS is what I am not able to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the rotated `:before` pseudo-element which you are using to mask the hero carousel which is bleeding off your screen, thus enlarging your external containers.

[image: The rotated element]

You can either apply `overflow-x: hidden` to your body element or fix the root of the problem by removing the `left`, `padding` from your pseudo-element and replacing your transform with `transform: skew(0, -5deg);` in this way you skew the container horizontally as you need keeping it straight vertical within the parent container.

---

**Bonus answer:**

The next time you have this same problem scroll into the empty area, click the first button on the top left of the Developer Tools window (Or just do `CTRL + Shift + C` with DevTools open) and then hover the mouse around on the white area like you're searching for the element, when it flashes up into your screen just click it and you can identify which element is causing you issues.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination..I dont understand CSS much can you tell me the lines to edit in css file ?

Comment: I did try overflow-x: hidden to body but it didnt fix the problem

Comment: The element you have to edit is `#thm-mart-slideshow:before` and you can find it in this file on line 32: `/site/easydelivery/stylesheet/revslider.css`

Comment: You made my day !! :) :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
* {margin: 0 auto; padding:0;}
```

And

```
body {
    margin: 0; padding:0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    background:#f5f5f5;
    line-height:1.6em;
    width:100%;  



}
```

Comment: tried it. didn't work :(